# Detecting index finger tip using HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am working on a college project using Microsoft HoloLens, Unity 2017.3.1f1 and HoloToolkit-Unity-2017.2.1.3. I need to have a sphere that moves with my index finger tip as an indicator. I created a sphere that at every frame it's position is changed according to my hand's position so it moves with my hand. I have a problem that it is placed at my palm. Is there any way that I can translate it so that it will be moving with my index finger tip? Maybe something as an offset? Any help with that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a gameobject with both your script and the 3d model?  You could move the model to a child gameobject, and offset that child by the amount of an average hand.
That way the parent tracks the position of the center of the palm, but the actual model is offset to the finger because children gameobjects move relative to their parents.

It might have issues with rotation, but should be a good starting point.

Comment: I tried this actually. You are right there is rotation problem as well as the direction is not that accurate. I made the translation in the z axis. Any help with these problems? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have another question, excuse me as I am somehow new to unity. Can you please tell me how to get the position of the sphere after having a parent and child game object?

Comment: Sorry, I'll recommend following the https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials tutorials through before getting going with anything else.  It'll be worth your time, and will answer all these questions in a far more robust way than I could in the comments section (: